My professor insists that this data is normally distributed but I cannot work out how that can be!
I have a data set on deforestation and the impact that the distance from a road has on deforestation. For the assignment, I need to assess the correlation between these two variables. In class, my professor told us to use both parametric linear regression and correlation to analyse the sets on R. However, when I came to do it myself, I got that the data was not normally distributed and therefore I couldn't use these parametric analyses.
My data gives very right skewed histograms and I have tested it with both shapiro-wilk and Kolmogorov-smirnov but they both say the data is not normal. I have used both these normality tests on single variables per test. The QQ plot is pretty straight and looks okay, but admittedly isn't completely perfect.
Am I missing something really obvious? Should I be transforming the data somehow? I'm pretty sure its fake data so I think there should be an answer that I'm just missing!
Data is all continuous (area of ranch, distance from road etc).
Would really appreciate any suggestions! Thanks :)
EDIT: I'm sorry I don't know how to upload my data but here are the histograms, as well as scatterplot with regression line and the QQ plot. Shaprio came back with 0.019 for distance and a teeny tiny p value for area. They need to be over 0.05 to be 'significant' though, right? Thanks!





It’s hard to comment on data and analysis that aren’t shared. Can you [edit] to include both?

"The QQ plot is pretty straight and looks okay, but admittedly isn't completely perfect." Notwithstanding the rest of your post, I would suggest not looking for complete perfection.

A nice illustration by @Glen_b of the variability in QQ plots even when the sample is drawn from a normal distribution: Interpreting QQplot - Is there any rule of thumb to decide for non-normality?

With respect to the last sentence of your first paragraph - neither correlation nor linear regression requires Normality to be valid.  Correlation assesses the strength of a linear relationship.  Linear regression models a linear relationship.  The idea that either requires Normality is a myth, albeit an oft-repeated one.

Have you considered log normality?

The normal distribution has support over the entire real line, and these are strictly positive values.

@Durden Unlikely, because the lognormal is not usually a good model for a variable that is limited above and has values approaching that limit.  The standard exploratory approaches to EDA will do just fine here: do a robust regression; use diagnostics like a spread vs. level plot to identify a suitable reexpression of the response; then identify suitable reexpressions of the explanatory variables to achieve an approximate linear relation.  But--returning to the question--there is abundant evidence that nothing here looks Normal: neither the marginal nor the conditional distributions.

Adding to @jbowman 's point, looking at your  correlation plot, there are no clear outliers or influential points - it looks fine. For regression, you can look at the normality of the residuals.

@Peter I believe that some appreciable amounts of nonlinearity, heteroscedasticity, and positively skewed conditional distributions are apparent from the plots.  This would likely be cured by simple re-expressions of one or both variables.
